# Why did the Ottomans 'never' enter wars during Napoleon's invasions?

Tags: napoleonic-wars, turkey

Without knowing about the subject, why Turkey never entered the fray during the Napoleonic wars?

It is true that they fought against the Russians around 1800's, but as far as I know, the engagement was on individual disputes between Russia and Turkey.

It seems strange that one of the main (although sick) empires never participated in the major battles of the Napoleonic wars. It is also weird that they neither gave material support to one of the parties, as was England's case.

Comment: By the way, "Turkey" to refer to the Ottoman Empire is, rightly or wrongly, not customary usage.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Doesn't getting attacked by Napoleon count as being "in the fray"?  Remember the famous [invasion of Egypt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/French_campaign_in_Egypt_and_Syria).  The Ottoman Empire governed Egypt at the time.

Comment: I guess I was thinking from 1805 onwards, the 'second phase' of Napoleon's empire. I didn't phrase the question correctly. My bad and ignorance pal :P

Comment: You make a good point about Egypt, but does this really answer the question? Why did Turkey not join one side or the other?

Comment: @LarsBosteen Question has changed a bit.  I think I answered the original just fine.  Feel free to answer the revised yourself.